# Unable to access virtual directory that points to a networked share

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, virtual-directory, windows-server-2016

I have a .NET 4.61 website running in IIS on Windows Server 2016.  The website is bound to an app pool. I've created a domain account which serves as the Identity for this app pool.

[image]

The website has a virtual directory in it called `images`.  This virtual directory points to a networked resource.

[image]

If I click `Test Settings...` button, everything works great:

[image]

However, if I access the site from the browser: http://10.10.121.11/images/someresource.htm, I get 
`401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.`

Now if I go into Advanced Settings for the `images`virtual directory and change the `Physical Path Credentials` to `Specific User` (instead of pass-through authentication) and enter the same exact user as I've entered for the app pool, everything works fine.  But I shouldn't have to do that.  Shouldn't the virtual directly inherit the app pool identity?

What am I missing?

Comment: kindly check the permission of the directory you are working.

Comment: @reds Permissions are there.  In fact, from my workstation, I can map a drive with those credentials and have no problem browsing or looking at the content of files.

Comment: I mean the folder properties and the user of this `Unauthorized: Access is denied`

Comment: I think this user `Unauthorized: Access is denied` must have an access to that folder.

Comment: @reds The user has read, list, execute permissions for the file and the folder.  I think IIS is ignoring the user and tries to connect as anonymous.

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/418716/Unauthorized-Access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-c